# Could a human brain downloaded into a robot have feelings?

Tags: science-based, brain, android

Some of you may have seen the miniseries "YEAR MILLION" by National Geographic.
It is a glimpse of how life will be in the future (despite the title, they don´t say specifically how many years from now). It is based on the achievements science could possibly have in a few centuries (so they say). In the first chapter, a girl is mortally wounded in an accident, and the insurance company gives her parents the option of downloading the girl´s brain into an android.
The parents agree, the insurance company takes the girl, and the parents go to the lab to receive a healthy and happy copy of their daughter. Besides being an exact robotic duplicate, the girl has a copy of every single thought of the girl since she was born. And her behavior is exactly the same.

Of course, she has now more "habilities" (enhanced senses, access to the internet directly with her brain, never gets old, to mention just a few...). And (here comes the weird part) she has the same feelings, the same sense of humor, and loves her parents as much as the original girl.

Human feelings and emotions are in part orchestrated by glands and organs outside of the brain (ovaries, testicles, adrenal glands, and so on...). So with no glands, the brand new computer brain of that girl will be immune to pherormones and many other chemical triggers. So, without all those chemical cocktails, can she still have feelings with her computer brain only?

Comment: This is an ongoing argument in philosophy of mind. Entire books have been written defending different variations of "yes" and "no", so it's unlikely that any answer here could possibly cover all of the issues. Plus, I'm not sure how it's a worldbuilding question; it's just a philosophy question. (From a worldbuilding perspective, people have written hundreds of perfectly good SF novels with both answers, so clearly there's no obvious answer forced on you.)

Comment: @abarnert The question isn't really asking about consciousness. It is merely asking about whether an artificial brain can convincingly simulate those human emotions which are triggered by chemicals in the brain. Whether the android has a consciousness which *actually* experiences those emotions or is just very good at convincing people that it does isn't really within the scope of the quesiton.

Comment: @Philipp Consciousness is only one part of the problem. If I have a robot and I program it to be act sad and be sad, does it feel sad? If everything is simulated, which is has to be because its a robot, does the robot actually feel anything. Or is it just obeying the lines of code inside it which dictate its actions and behavior.

Comment: this depends on the robot and how the brain is recreated in the robot. remember a brain with no glands does not function, (nerve signals are chemical signals) the signals from your eyes is also chemical, brains are not digital.

Comment: @Shadowzee "If everything is simulated, which is has to be because its a robot…" Why? You're assuming the answer. You might just as well say, "If everything is simulated, which it has to be because it's just an electrochemical soup" and therefore humans can't have real feelings.

Comment: @abarnert This is literally how the philosophical argument starts. You are taking a real person and creating an android copy of them. the android isn't the original and everything it knows was transferred from an analog system into a digital system. Thats real world data converted into zeros and ones. A continuous spectrum represented in a discrete system. Its like representing a real number 100% accurately in binary. Its close, but not perfect.

Comment: As always, I hate to see a question with such a solid answer being put on a site like this which is more for worldbuilding than computational neuroscience and information theory.

Comment: We don't know if and how downloading minds would work, so any answer would be a guess.

Comment: I added a little more to my answer, including the concepts of a Turing Test and the Chinese Room.  I see you have already picked an answer, but if you want to dig further into the philosophical implications of the question, those are two concepts that I highly recommend exploring.

Comment: @Shadowzee No physical process requires infinite precision to describe, or the universe would quite literally implode (infinite information requires infinite mass due to the Bekenstein bound, and infinite mass will cause the universe to curve so much that it curls into a single point).

Comment: @forest The problem is already present when trying to represent a single decimal place. If someone wanted to work in nano meters, suddenly the error can be huge. 0.1 in half-precision is 0.0999755859375. If I want to know how many times a 1 nano meter wavelength will fluctuate over 0.1 meters, I'm going to get a huge error, unless you represent 0.1 using a huge number of bits. The point isn't that I need infinite precision. I'm saying that a computer can only simulate an analogue system because its a digital system.

Comment: @Shadowzee Ah I see what you mean. Yeah while it is possible, it's _exceptionally_ difficult. Like even neural simulators tend to simulate very primitive models of neurons (even M-P neurons), whereas a full simulation taking into account molecular motion takes a supercomputer to simulate even a single _ion channel_ in real time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The human brain is a neural network which can be [emulated by a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network).

Psychoactive chemicals (like hormones or psychoactive drugs) affect that neural network in the brain by stimulating synapses or preventing their stimulation. If you want to create a perfect simulation of a human mind, then you will have to simulate this too. You can emulate an adrenalin gland, for example, by adding random signals to all neurons which have [adrenergic receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenergic_receptor).

This would make the simulation more complicated. In order to copy a human brain, you don't just need to scan which neurons are connected by which synapses, but also the exact receptor configuration of each synapse. The neurotransmitter simulation would also require much more memory and processing power than a "conventional" neural network of the same complexity which just simulates pure neuron-neuron interactions. But if you have the necessary brain-scanning technology and if you are able to throw enough computer hardware at the problem, then neither seems to be implausible.

Answer (score 5):

Just to head this one off, the answer is "maybe."  We know so little about this that we don't even know what we don't know.  Whether or not our "feelings" are unique to our human bodies or something that would be copied around with our brain is an open question in philosophy.  Some argue that our feelings and qualia would be downloaded along with the brain.  Others argue they would not.  Others would argue that the concept of an AI with feelings is not even sufficiently meaningful to form a question about it.  The topic is that unknown today.

Now if you had asked whether people would empirically observe her as having feelings, that's a different question than asking whether she actually has feelings.  It's the difference between passing a [Turing Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) and *being* human.  I think it is generally believed that a sufficiently advanced computer simulation could fool other people into believing it has feelings, can experience "love," etc.  However, we can't answer the question of whether or not computers can have feelings without first defining what feelings are.  We can't answer whether the computer can love without first defining "love."  Over the course of human history, attempts to define these words have been fraught with difficulty.

The classic example of this is the [Chinese Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room), a thought experiment put forth by John Searle.  In this experiment, the question is raised whether *simulating* an understanding of Chinese is the same concept as *understanding* Chinese.  That argument is still being debated to this day, and language is a *much* simpler concept to work with than feelings are.

If you were writing a story, my recommendation would be to pick an answer, and write to it.  You will find ample philosophical and biological arguments for whatever answer you choose to go with.

Comment: -1 It's not an open question at all, at least not in computational neuroscience, which is the field where people actually _study_ the brain. Only hardcore dualists try to believe in the "ghost in the machine". The fact is, we _know_ that, if a brain were to be perfectly cloned into another Turing-complete computing medium, it would be functionally identical to a real brain. Now, whether or not we will ever be able to _perform_ such a cloning, we don't know. But from an information theoretic standpoint, we do know. And yes, even neurophenomenologists agree with this.

Comment: @forest Interesting.  Everything I have read says the opposite.  For instance, the value of Turing completeness is almost immediately called into question, and indeed it is not clear if it is even physically possible to clone a brain in the first place, or whether physics would simply get in the way.

Comment: Turing-completeness allows _any_ computation. Our brains are, of course, Turing-complete.

Comment: @forest That's the simplified version of it.  Our brains lack an infinite piece of tape.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. The infinite piece of tape is a Turing machine. Turing-completeness allows for simulation of a Turing machine if resources are unbounded. That's why even an Atmel 8051 is Turing-complete, despite having a mere 128 bytes of RAM. You don't need infinite memory to perform computation in a Turing-complete way.

Comment: @forest Oh, you're referring to the weak version of the term "turing complete" which is used when taking a Turing Complete abstract machine and implementing it on hardware, where it ceases to be able to do *any* computation.  There's a bit of a chicken and the egg problem there, don't you think?  If we start from the assumption that the brain is emulatable by a turing machine, surely the brain is emulatable by a turing machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82752/discussion-between-forest-and-cort-ammon).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Depending on how the copy is implemented. If it runs like a real mind with quadrillions of nodes and synapses firing in a certain order and memory and personality being captured in the relationship between input and output, with some patterned self-talk within the brain.

While the hormones may be gone, the effects may be simulated. Adrenaline streamlines thinking, focusing on the topic at hand and suppressing side talk. Thinking becomes faster, but more narrow-minded and prone to blindness. Cortisol ignores pain signals, endorphins similarly focus thinking around a goal. Empathy is based on a specialized part of the brain that simulated us being in the situation we are perceiving. The effects of testosterone and estrogen on the brain are still arguable, and whatever they are, likely can be similarly achieved.